# Generating sql file with uuids and referring those ids further postgres9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a sql file which has uuids as primary key. Here is how my create table definition looks like using pgcrypto extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;  
CREATE TABLE snw.contacts(  
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
   name TEXT,
   email TEXT
);
```

Now I add a record in this table using

```
INSERT INTO snw.contacts (name,email) VALUES('Dr Nic Williams','drnic');

postgres=# select * from snw.contacts;
                  id                  |      name       | email
--------------------------------------+-----------------+-------
 7c627ee0-ac94-40ee-b39d-071299a55c13 | Dr Nic Williams | drnic
```

Now going ahead in the same file I want to insert a row in one of tables which looks like

```
CREATE TABLE snw.address(  
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
   street TEXT
   contact UUID
);
```

where contact UUID refers to ID in snw.contacts table. How can I fetch the uuid which was generated in the first insert and use it in another insert in the snw.address table?Something like:

```
INSERT INTO snw.address(street,contact) values('ABC', (select id from snw.contacts where email='drnic'));
```

I can use where clause I am using this script for generating some test data and so I know what the email would be for fetching the id.

Comment: Why the `sql-server` tag ?

Comment: I removed the apparently unrelated `sql-server` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [data modifying CTE:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_contact as (
  INSERT INTO snw.contacts (name,email) 
  VALUES('Dr Nic Williams','drnic')
  returning id
)
INSERT INTO snw.address(street,contact)
select 'ABC', id
from new_contact;
```